# select2 dropdown appearing messy on bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

HTML code -

```
<div class="block">
    <label class="control-label-required">Deposit to account </label><br />
    <select id="receipt_voucher_to_account_id" name="receipt_voucher[to_account_id]">
    <option value="1">sbi</option>
    <option value="2">cash in hand</option>
    <option value="3">Loan and advances</option>
    <option value="4">HDFC Bank acc</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Jquery code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#receipt_voucher_to_account_id").select2();
      $("#receipt_voucher_to_account_id").removeAttr('tabindex');
    });
</script>
```

Output - 
[image]

Dropdown is not appearing properly in the bootstrap modal. I found one solution that ask me to remove attribute tabindex, I follow this but still getting same issue. Can any buddy help me please. Thanks!!

Comment: looks like you are missing the CSS

Comment: i wanna see you code for your modal. dropdown code works fine.

Comment: I added the css properly and this is working fine everywhere except on modal box

Answer (score 0):

> Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports
>   searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

It looks like this plug-in is interfering with the normal bootstrap.

What happens if you comment out `$("#receipt_voucher_to_account_id").select2();` and reload the page?

Have you checked the FireFox/Chrome console for any css/js related errors?

Comment: Showing simple dropdown after comment this code. No any error showing in console.